# Debugging encoding problems (R XML)

Tags: xml, r, debugging, encoding, xml-parsing

Is there a way to locate an encoding problem within an XML file? I'm trying to parse such a file (let's call it `doc`) with the `XML` library in `R`, but there seems to be a problem with the encoding.

```
xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, asText=TRUE)
Error: Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content.
Error: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding!
Error: Premature end of data in tag ...
```

and a list of tags with presumably premature end of data follows. However, I'm pretty sure that no premature ends exist in this document.

Ok, so next try:

```
doc <- iconv(doc, to="UTF-8")
doc <- sub("utf-16", "utf-8", doc)
xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, asText=T)
Error: Premature end of data in tag...
```

and again a list of tags follows along with line numbers. I've checked the lines and I can't find any errors.

Another suspicion: the "µ"-character that occurs in the document might cause the error. So next try:

```
doc <- iconv(doc, to="UTF-8")
doc <- gsub("µ", "micro", doc)
doc <- sub("utf-16", "utf-8", doc)
xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, asText=T)
Error: Premature end of data in tag...
```

Any other suggestions for debugging?

*EDIT:* After having spent two days with trying to fix the error, I still haven't found a solution. However, I think I have narrowed down the possible answers. Here is what I've found:

- copying the `XML` string from the source database into a file and saving it as a separate `xml` file in Notepad++ --> `Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content`.
- changing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` (or `encoding="latin1"`) within this file --> **no error**
- reading `XML` string from database via `doc <- sqlQuery(myconn, query.text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE); doc <- doc[1,1]`, manipulating it with `str_sub(doc, 35, 36) <- "8"` or `str_sub(doc, 31, 36) <- "latin1"` and then trying to parse it with `xmlInternalTreeParse(doc)` --> `Premature end of data in tag...`
- reading the `XML` string from database as above and then trying to parse it with `xmlInternalTreeParse(doc)` --> `Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content. Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE4 0x64 0x2E 0x20 Premature end of data in tag...` (list of tags follows).
- reading the `XML` string from database as above and parsing with `xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, encoding="latin1")` --> `Premature end of data in tag...`
- using `doc <- iconv(doc[1,1], to="UTF-8")` or `to="latin1"` before parsing doesn't change anything

I would appreciate any suggestions very much.

Comment: It's extremely hard to answer a question of this nature without a reproducible example

Comment: @hadley I don't have any idea how to provide an MWE here. When I change "UTF-16" to "UTF-8" in the document header and then copy the content of this file into another empty file and save it in exactly the same way, the `Document labelled UTF-16...` error disappears. Changing the header in the original file and saving the changes doesn't help. But I can't use this procedure every time as I need this script to automatically process data from a database. I'm puzzled and don't know how to debug or even how to provide an example as it seems not to be the content itself that causes the problem.

Comment: I know I debugged a similar problem a couple of months ago, but I can't remember exactly what I did.  One other thing you can experiment with is to load the xml with `xmlInternalTreeParse(file(doc, encoding = "utf-16"))` and see if setting the encoding there helps.

Comment: @hadley Thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my first posting and listed the things I've tried so far. I did try to specifiy the encoding, but this doesn't help. Oddly enough, replacing `utf-16` by `utf-8` or by `latin1` within the saved file with Notepad++ solves the problem. But doing the same by string manipulation after having imported the XML-string from SQL database into an `R` object doesn't help.

Comment: FYI your `iconv` call is unlikely to be correct - you usually need to specify both from and to.

Comment: @hadley I found out that this way it works for short XML files (even without specifiying the `from` argument), and after having a closer look at the file which is not working, I found that apparently the file gets chopped off. So it seems there were two problems: retrieving and encoding. The one with the encoding is solved now. I opened a new question on how to retrieve large strings as I think it's not within the scope of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525539/how-to-retrieve-a-very-long-xml-string-from-an-sql-database-with-r Anyway, thanks a lot for  your suggestions!

Comment: @AnjaM you might answer your own question now that you have the answer to at least part of it.  I found your `doc <- gsub("utf-16", "utf-8", doc); doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, asText=T)` snippet useful in parsing output from the Coding Analysis Toolkit http://cat.ucsur.pitt.edu/, but almost left the page when I saw your question didn't have an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The encoding problem occurred because the encoding of the original XML file and the encoding within the SQL database where the XML content was stored as `longtext` didn't match. Substituting the specification of the encoding within the XML string and converting this string solved the problem:

```
doc <- sqlQuery(myconn, query.text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
doc <- iconv(doc[1,1], to="UTF-8")
doc <- sub("utf-16", "utf-8", doc)
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(doc, asText = TRUE)
```

Truncating of the XML string during retrieval from the database turned out to be a separate problem. The solution is provided here: [How to retrieve a very long XML-string from an SQL database with R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525539/how-to-retrieve-a-very-long-xml-string-from-an-sql-database-with-r?lq=1)