# how to scrape this squawka page?

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract the following information:

On the page

http://epl.squawka.com/stoke-city-vs-arsenal/01-03-2014/english-barclays-premier-league/matches

pressing the red "full stats" button opens a menu that includes (on the left hand side) the button "Crosses". This opens, on the right side of the screen, an image of a soccer pitch with 19 arrows on it, these are the cross passes by Stoke in the Stoke-Arsenal match. They are color coded, red=not completed, green = completed, yellow = key passes.
When you click on an arrow, it will tell you who gave the pass and in what minute of the game.
Also, the arrows show where the player was standing when he gave the pass and where the player was who was being passed to.

I would like to be able to scrape this page such that I get a table with the columns:

team; name-of-sender; location-of-sender; location-of-receiver; minute; color-of-arrow

This is the set of cross passes made by Stoke, I also would like to automatically repeat this for Arsenal (hence, the column "club" in the table above).

Although I have scraped webpages in the past, these have all been static fairly straighforward pages, and I am totally dumbfounded as to how to scrape the info from this page. 
I would really appreciate help as to how to scrape the data I just described. I am well-versed in R, so I would especially appreciate code that would help me achieve this in R, but I am also quite appreciative of help that uses other language or software.

Thank you,
Peter

Comment: You will probably have to use a browser driver, such as Selenium. There are R interfaces; see http://lluisramon.github.io/relenium/ and http://johndharrison.github.io/RSelenium/.

Comment: I had never heard of such a thing, new homework! How would I use that to scrape a page like this one at squawka? Any hints?

Comment: There's a nice example of how to use Selenium with `R` just [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22123344/1036500), currently an answer to the question directly above yours on the the [R tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Peter as the guys indicated you can do this with Selenium. I also like to use the excellent [selectr package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/selectr/index.html)
The idea is to briefly interact with the site then do the rest elsewhere. squawkData should contain everything needed.

```
# RSelenium::startServer() # if needed
require(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$setImplicitWaitTimeout(3000)
remDr$navigate("http://epl.squawka.com/stoke-city-vs-arsenal/01-03-2014/english-barclays-premier-league/matches")
squawkData <- remDr$executeScript("return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(squawkaDp.xml);", list())
require(selectr)
example <- querySelectorAll(xmlParse(squawkData[[1]]), "crosses time_slice")
example[[1]]


<time_slice name="0 - 5" id="1">
  <event player_id="531" mins="4" secs="39" minsec="279" team="44" type="Failed">
    <start>73.1,87.1</start>
    <end>97.9,49.1</end>
  </event>
</time_slice>
```

DISCLAIMER I am the author of the RSelenium package. A basic vignette on operation can be viewed at [RSelenium basics](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843) and 
[RSelenium: Testing Shiny apps](http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/13408).

Further info can be accessed easily using selectr:

```
> xmlValue(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(squawkData[[1]]), "players #531 name")[[1]])
[1] "Charlie Adam"

> xmlValue(querySelectorAll(xmlParse(squawkData[[1]]), "game team#44 long_name")[[1]])
[1] "Stoke City"
```

UPDATE:
To process example into a dataframe you can do something like

```
out <- lapply(example, function(x){
# handle each event
  if(length(x['event']) > 0){
    res <- lapply(x['event'], function(y){
      matchAttrs <- as.list(xmlAttrs(y))
      matchAttrs$start <- xmlValue(y['start']$start)
      matchAttrs$end <- xmlValue(y['end']$end)
      matchAttrs
    })
    return(do.call(rbind.data.frame, res))
  }
}
)

> head(do.call(rbind, out))
        player_id mins secs minsec team   type     start       end
event         531    4   39    279   44 Failed 73.1,87.1 97.9,49.1
event5        311    6   33    393   31 Failed 92.3,13.1 93.0,31.0
event1        376    8   57    537   31 Failed  97.7,6.1 96.7,16.4
event6        311   13   50    830   31 Failed  99.5,0.5 94.9,42.6
event11       311   14   11    851   31 Failed  99.5,0.5 93.1,51.0
event7        311   17   41   1061   31 Failed 99.5,99.5 92.6,50.1
```

Comment: Thank you, John, this works very well, I have been studying it for several hours now. 
 
I have two remaining questions:1. how did you know to address "squawkaDp.xml"? 
 
2. I would ike to generate a dataframe (or something like that) with columns 


 
player_id, mins, secs, minsec, team, type, startX, startY, endX, endY
 
which would read

531, 4, 39, 279, 44, "Failed", 73.1, 87.1, 97.9, 49.1
311, 6", 33, 393, 31, "Failed", 92.3, 13.1, 93.0, 31.0
376, 8, 57, 537, 31, "Failed", 97.7, 6.1, 96.7, 16.4
et cetera (for a total of 38 rows)
How can I do that? XMLNodeSets always totally escape me..

Comment: @PeterVerbeet Im glad the example worked for you. It would have been possible to start clicking buttons etc on the site however the data is contained in a Scalable Vector Graphics format. It was easier to get the source. I looked at http://epl.squawka.com/scripts/squawkaDp_v10.30.js?v=7 in this file search for `showCrosses function:` and in this function note the line `var crosses  =  $(squawkaDp.xml).find('crosses')` . With regards to your 2nd question I will add a quick pointer in the code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John, this works brilliantly! I clearly need to dive into some literature to be able to further understand and do this on other websites. Any tips?
At any rate, I will be making use of your RSelenium package quiet a lot in the future, thanks for your very useful help and time!

Comment: One additional issue that has come up. I tried to do the exact same thing for "http://eredivisie.squawka.com/feyenoord-vs-ajax/02-03-2014/dutch-eredivisie/matches" and when I run "xmlParse(squawkData[[1]])" I get an error: "Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE8 0x22 0x2C 0x22." Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: This is an issue with the squawka site. They are sending utf8 data but it contains other encoding. use `example <- querySelectorAll(xmlParse(gsub('encoding="UTF-8"', 'encoding="ISO-8859-1"', squawkData[[1]])), "crosses time_slice")` for a quick fix but there maybe issues with this.

Comment: See other examples of this issue like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507608/error-input-is-not-proper-utf-8-indicate-encoding-using-phps-simplexml-lo and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495133/debugging-encoding-problems-r-xml

Comment: Thanks John, gsub solved it. The resulting data appear to be correct, thanks a lot! (I had already tried iconv, but that really messed up the xml, your solution works much better)